# What is the other way instead of using onchange in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Good day!

> Currently I have this jquery onchange function with the use of this function you need to click it first for it to change, in this code I'm using select tag so whenever I click it it shows a table;

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#year").change(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "../templates/student_template.php",
                data: {
                    "course": $("#course").val(),
                    "semester": $("#semester").val(),
                    "year": $("#year").val(),
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#total_fees").html(data);
                }
            });
        });     
    });
```

> Now, what I wanted to do is that I don't want to click it anymore no matter what is the value of select tag like when the page loads it should load automatically display without clicking, What function should I use for that?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to call your `$.ajax` method directly inside `$(document).ready` like this.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "../templates/student_template.php",
                data: {
                    "course": $("#course").val(),
                    "semester": $("#semester").val(),
                    "year": $("#year").val(),
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#total_fees").html(data);
                }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Just try with this,hopefully it will resolve your issue

$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#year').trigger('change');
});
```

and add remaining code outside the document.ready(),like

```
$("#year").change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "../templates/student_template.php",
            data: {
                "course": $("#course").val(),
                "semester": $("#semester").val(),
                "year": $("#year").val(),
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#total_fees").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
```